# How to get wms layer name on click. I tried it in different ways but I am not getting. I have 3 wms layers in this way

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have 3 wms layers in this way how to get wms 
layer name of these layers

```
var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible : false,
    source : new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url : 'http://192.168.4.229:8080/geoserver/geodata/wms',
        params : {
            'FORMAT' : 'image/png',
            'VERSION' : '1.1.1',
            "LAYERS" : 'geodata:ht_line',
            tiled : true,
            "exceptions" : 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the map's `forEachLayerAtPixel` method:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  map.forEachLayerAtPixel(e.pixel, function(layer) {
    // log the LAYERS param of the WMS source
    console.log(layer.getSource().getParams().LAYERS);
  });
});
```